Build and Train an image to C# object ML model using ML.Net
I wish to build/train an ML model that can scan a question paper, get a list of Questions, question Images(if any), and Question options(if any) then return it as a c# object as output.
I have extensive knowledge of C#, but all the Ml.Net lessons I have seen so far are text and label.
Kindly point me in the right direction
I have tried using Azure congitive, all i get is object and face recognition.
I want to be able to get list of questions and their question image and/or question options
